# Short story of a race who discovered primitive but subtle interstellar travel

Tags: story-identification, ftl-drive, space, short-stories

Many years (20+?) ago in Analog SF magazine I read a short story where a culture discovered interstellar travel shortly after the start of their iron age. They could construct air-tight ships and travel essentially as far as their oxygen supply lasted. Before they met us, the most technologically advanced culture they came across had discovered balloon flight. Needless to say they thought our jets were merely improved balloons.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Pretty sure that's [The Road Not Taken](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Road_Not_Taken_%28short_story%29) by Harry Turtledove.

Comment: Never read that, but I have read the sequel *Herbig-Haro* as anthologized in *Republic and Empire* or something like that. A good story.